# Creating a class with parameters in the constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I know it could be a trivial question, but I am stuck with it. I have googled for a while but didn't manage to make it work.

I have one class with one constructor with some parameters, its definition is this:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    int _myInt;
    double _myDouble;
    std::vector<double> _myVector;

public:
    MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, std::vector<double> myVector);
    MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, otherVectorClass myVector);

    int getMyInt();
    double getMyDouble();
    std::vector<double> getMyVector();
};

MyClass::MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, std::vector<double> myVector) {
    _myInt = myInt;
    _myDouble = myDouble;
    _myVector = myVector;
}

MyClass::MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, otherVectorClass myVector) {
    std::vector<double> tempVector = functionTransformingSTDVector(myVector);
    MyClass(myInt, myDouble, tempVector);
}

// getters
int MyClass::getMyInt() { return _myInt; }
double MyClass::getMyDouble() { return _myDouble; }
std::vector<double> MyClass::getMyVector() { return _myVector; }
```

And in another method I instantiate it with the following code:

```
std::vector<MyClass> myContainer;
int j = 0;
while(j<10) {
    j++;
    double d = 0.04;
    otherVectorClass v = function_returning_vector(); // It works fine.
    MyClass anInstance(j, d, v);
    myContainer.push_back(anInstance);
}
```

I have come to find my error, I call second constructor, that one transform special case of "vector" into std::vector and calls the first constructor, but the private variables on the first constructor change as expected, but do not on the original constructor call.

If I change the second constructor to transform the vector, and assign variables directly, then everything works fine.

How can I call one constructor from another, to avoid code repeating.

Thank you.

Comment: "as "anInstance" has lost all the values, and has been reset." - how do you know this? What values has it been "reset" to?

Comment: Maybe your default copy constructor isn't set up right. As a tip: `MyClass::MyClass(...) : _myInt(myInt), _myDouble(_myDouble), myVector(myVector)` is the easier way to link these up.

Comment: @tadman He doesn't need a copy constructor.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Fair enough.

Comment: Instead of `MyClass::MyClass(...) : ..., _myVector(myVector)` I would use `MyClass::MyClass(...) : ..., _myVector(std::move(myVector))` .

Comment: @DanielSchepler it does not matter in this example

Comment: I can not tell if your are using a debugger or not.  How did you 'trace' the values?    If you won't try gdb, consider adding a method, perhaps "MyClass::show()".  Use it several places, including prior and after push_back().  i.e. anInstance.show() and perhaps myContainer[0].show()

Comment: Neil Butterworth, I know it because I am using Xcode, and can see instant values at each step. ej: j = 2, d = 0.04, v = {one vector}, when anInstance is created _myInt = 2, _myDouble = 0.04, v = {vector}, but when try to store in myContainer values for _myInt =(int)2771456, _myDouble = (double)6.9532E-310 and _myVector has nothing

Comment: @radulum Post all the code.

Comment: I have edited the code, I have found the exact problem but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have come to understand exactly what was happening, I'm new to c++, and the problem was due to the overloading of constructors, more exactly with **delegating overloaded constructors**.

Once I knew which the problem was, I found the solution quickly. Thank you all for your advices and clues.

In this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Object_construction_improvement), is the answer, adapting the code to my case:

```
public:
    MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, std::vector<double> myVector) { // code for the initialization };
    MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, otherVectorClass myVector) : MyClass(myInt, myDouble, functionTransformingSTDVector(myVector)) { // some code if needed after initialization };
```

I need to perform some calculus before call to the 'main' constructor, so I tried to find if it is possible to do the call from the body of the constructor, but in this other [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/133063/constructors-in-c11/), on "C++11 Delegating Constructors" says that it not can be done, because what happens is that a temporary object is created inside the scope of the new instance, and deleted quickly afterwards, this behavior is not what I was expecting.

So one possible solution is to create a function like 'functionTransformingSTDVector(...)' to perform the calculus, like the example posted above, or create one function that initializes the common parts and call it from the constructors:

```
private:
    void construct(int myInt, double myDouble, std:vector<double> myVector) {
        _myInt = myInt;
        _myDouble = myDouble;
        _myVector = myVector;
    }

public:
    MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, std::vector<double> myVector) {
        // Do the calculus needed
        construct(myInt, myDouble, myVector); };
    MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, otherVectorClass myVector) {
        // Do the calculus needed
        construct(myInt, myDouble, tempVector); };
```

Hope this could help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You should use initialization instead of assignment. Initialization is where you provide a value for the variable at its moment of creation; as opposed to having it take a default value and then assign a value later as you are currently doing.

You can use a delegating constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, otherVectorClass myVector)
    : MyClass(myInt, myDouble, functionTransforming(myVector))
{
}
```

Although since the delegated operations are so simple it might be better not to:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int myInt, double myDouble, otherVectorClass myVector)
    : _myInt(myInt), _myDouble(myDouble), _myVector(functionTransformingSTDVector(myVector))
{
}
```

You can and should make a similar change to the other constructor, to use initialization instead of assignment. (Also, use `std::move(myVector)` in that constructor).

Comment: I am new, why do you say I should use initialization instead of assignment? I usually tend to have one private function 'setDefault', to assign a default value to all properties, especially when not all the variables are among the constructor's parameters...and it help me to reset all the properties if needed.